# there are no sql server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer while installing service pack2

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQLServer2012 in my system , And I have downloaded the SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU , while installing the SP2 , I am getting the no instance error in "select features" step.

My system is windows 7 and 64bit.

Comment: I have installed SQL server 2012 before install of SP2

Comment: Any one could you please help me to resolve the error